# Function that takes file as input

Tags: python

I want to define a function that takes a file name, and runs the file through some code. I have completed the latter part, but I'm stuck at the first part. Here is where I'm having trouble:

```
def function(inputfilename):
    file = open("inputfilename","r")
```

example input and the error I get:

```
>>>function("file.csv")
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'inputfilename'
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Ask yourself; When something is contained in quotes, is it a variable or a string?

Comment: I feel so stupid right now :(

Comment: Nah, you just need more caffeine!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are trying to open a file with `inputfilename` name.

Replace:

```
file = open("inputfilename", "r")
```

with:

```
file = open(inputfilename, "r")
```

Also, consider using [with](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/compound_stmts.html#with) context manager while working with files.